# Floating divs not displayed in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

OK I don't see what's wrong here:

https://www.e-capture.net

When browsing this site in IE7, the divs with IDs #blog and #social are not being displayed. The reason seems to be the #content div, which has a different height in IE7 vs IE8/FF/Chrome. But I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

*Fun fact: the site displays better in IE6 than it does in IE7 :-)*

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this in IE7 and Firefox.

You just need to move around a bunch of your `<div>` tags, and add a single new one (*highlighted below*).

Here's what Firebug looked like after I'd finished:

[image: Firebug]

(*I did the same thing in IE7 first, and it fixed your problem. Then, I did the same in Firefox to make sure the fix won't kill it in modern browsers.*)

Here's my attempt at a textual description of what I did:

- I moved `#blog`, `#social` and `#footer` respectively to outside and after `#content`.
- I wrapped a new `<div>` around `#blog` and `#social`, with these styles:
  `margin: 0 auto; width: 960px`.
- I swapped around a few things concerning `#buttons`, to make them consistent between FF and IE7:

  - On `ul#buttons li`, remove `margin: 10px 0`, and add `float: left`.
  - On `ul#buttons li a`, remove `float: left` and add `display: block`.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot, now everything looks consistent cross-browser